# валидация по длине

Tags: python, валидация

подскажите, пожалуйста новичку, как добавить в код проверку что name не короче 3 символов и не длиннее 100 символов. Иначе возвращать "ERROR"

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from datetime import datetime
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

db_file = "./data/db.json"
json_db = open(db_file, "rb")
data = json.load(json_db)
messages_list = data["messages_list"]


def save_messages():
    data = {
        "messages_list": messages_list,
    }
    json_db = open(db_file, "w")
    json.dump(data, json_db)


def print_message(message):
    print(f"[{message['sender']}]: {message['text']} / {message['date']}")
    print('-' * 50)


def add_message(name, txt):
    message = {
        "text": txt,
        "sender": name,
        "date": datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    }

    messages_list.append(message)


@app.route("/")
def index_page():
    return "Hello, welcome to Skillbox chat"


@app.route("/get_messages")
def get_messages():
    return {"messages": messages_list}


@app.route("/send_message")
def send_message():
    name = request.args["name"]
    text = request.args["text"]
    add_message(name, text)
    save_messages()
    return "OK"


@app.route("/form")
def form():
    return render_template("form.html")


app.run()
```

Comment: `if len(name) < 3 of len(name) > 100: return 'ERROR"`

Comment: `if not (3 <= len(name) <= 100):`

Answer (score 2):

```
name = request.args["name"]

if len(name) in range(3, 101): 
    return "OK"

return "ERROR"
```

Comment: Кстати, хорошая проверка через `range`